# 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '(ViewController) -> () -> ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myAction: ((Int, Bool) -> Void)? = { [weak self] int, bool in

    }
}
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. I thought `self` should be an instance of `ViewController`, how is it becoming  `'(ViewController) -> () -> ViewController'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point when your property initializer runs, `self` is not yet available. You'll need to use [lazy loading](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-lazy-variables) — which is pretty easy. Just add `lazy` in front of the var.

```
lazy var myAction: ((Int, Bool) -> Void)? = { [weak self] int, bool in
    
}
```

Comment: ftw as per usual.